# In how many ways can the letters of the word EQUATION be arranged if vowels and consonants occur together?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many words with or without meaning can be formed using all the letters of the word "EQUATION" at a time if vowels and consonants occur together.
My answer is $5!3!2!=1440$.  Am I right?

Comment: Looks OK to me.  There are only 2 groups, 5 distinct vowels and 3 distinct consonants which can be independently permuted and the groups themselves can be permuted.

Answer (score 0):

In the word "EQUATION" there are 3 consonants (Q,T,N) so there are $3!$ ways to arrange and 5 vowels (E,U,A,I,O) so $5!$ ways to arrange. In whole for both first consonant and then vowels or vice-versa, there are $2!$ ways .
so in total $2! \cdot 5! \cdot  3!=1440$ ways.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  This Question is almost two years old, and essentially you repeat the confirmation requested by the Question given in a previous Comment, but you are certainly allowed to do so.  However I'd encourage you to improve the formatting, both as to capitalization and punctuation/spacing, and learn to [post with mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) using $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 0):

YES, you are correct. To form words using all the letters of the word "EQUATION" such that vowels and consonants occur together, you can follow these steps:

Group the vowels together: E, U, A, I, O ($5$ vowels)
Group the consonants together: Q, T, N ($3$ consonants)
Now treat the groups of vowels and consonants as single entities.

1. Arrange the two groups (vowels and consonants) in $2!$ ways.
2. Within the group of vowels, you can arrange the $5$ vowels in $5!$ ways.
3. Within the group of consonants, you can arrange the $3$ consonants
   in $3!$ ways.

So, the total number of words with or without meaning that can be formed is:

$$2! × 5! × 3! = 2 × 120 × 6 = 1440$$